# Why is eslint not working on Vite like it did on Create-React-App

Tags: eslint, create-react-app, vite

I am trying to embrace using Vite over Create React App, however the Eslint is a mess.

CRA process:
create a new react app using create react app, eslint works nicely.

Vite process:
create a new react app using vite, eslint is a mess and needs to be manually configured?

Am I missing something? Feels like Vite is more config heavy than CRA?

Comment: vite just is a tool  to build your code, for eslint/stylelint you need manually configure or use other templates